# ASIHTTPRequest on www.blau.de?

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I need to login here. I've tried the ASIHTTPRequest and ASIFormDataRequest.

None of them works as expected. I only got the data from the loginpage in the response string, not the data from the secure area.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.blau.de/"]];
[request setPostValue:@"USERNAME" forKey:@"quickLoginNumber"];
[request setPostValue:@"PASSWORD" forKey:@"quickLoginPassword"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: The ASIHTTPRequest Google group is probably a good place for this question, as well: http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of good tools you can use to try to debug this. In all likelihood there is a 302 redirect after logging in. You can watch for that (among other conditions) using tools such as:

- HTTPScoop (worth the $15 bux): http://www.tuffcode.com/
- Live Headers (a free FireFox plugin): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/

Keep in mind that what you're trying to do is not simple. I've gotten it to work with some sites, but not others and the reasons for one or the other can be quite elusive.